# How to stop RXJava 2 from emitting more errors after the first one?

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

using RX Java 2.2.6.

I understand that when a single error is emitted then the full stream stops. But if there is multiple errors emitted then I get...

`The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with.`

So in the below situation, my observable is created from a file stream that sends line by line. When the myService (http service) instance for example is down, then multiple errors are emitted. As multiple lines have been pushed to the service. So if the file had 10 lines, the first error will complete the observable, but then another 9 error will be emitted but at that time the observable is closed and I want it closed.

Should I switch myService to a Single rather than a Completable?

The myService for now is handler based and as to why I'm create the Completable wrapper.

```
observable
  .skipLast(1)
  .map(buffer -> new JsonArray(buffer))
  .flatMap(record ->
    Completable.create(emitter -> {
      if (record.size() > 13) {
        myService.send(..., writeResult -> {
          if (writeResult.succeeded()) {
            emitter.onComplete();
          } else {
            emitter.onError(writeResult.cause());
          }
        });
      } else {
        emitter.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Record contains invalid amount of elements. Found: " + record.size() + " elements."));
      }
    }).toObservable())
  .doOnComplete(() -> {
    resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(successCount.longValue()));
  }).subscribe(
  o -> {
  },
  t -> {
    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(t));
  });
```

**Update:** Checking if the emitter is disposed of seems to do the trick?

```
observable
.skipLast(1)
.map(buffer -> new JsonArray(buffer.getDelegate()))
.flatMap(record ->
  Completable.create(emitter -> {

          myService.send(..., writeResult -> {
            if (writeResult.succeeded()) {
              successCount.getAndIncrement();

              if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                emitter.onComplete();
            } else {
              if (!emitter.isDisposed())
                emitter.onError(writeResult.cause());
            }
          });
        } else {
          if(!emitter.isDisposed())
            emitter.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid topic."));
        }
  }).toObservable())
.doOnComplete(() -> {
  resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(successCount.longValue()));
}).subscribe(
o -> {
  // Do nothing
},
t ->
  resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(new IllegalStateException("Failed at line: " + successCount.get(), t)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `flatMapCompletable` will do the trick:

```
fun observeRecordings(): Observable<Unit> =
        Observable.just(20)
                .skipLast(1)
                .map { JsonArray(it) }
                .filter { it.size() > 13 }
                .flatMapCompletable { service.send(it) }
                .doOnError { }
                .toObservable()
```

Sorry for the use of Kotlin!

Comment: Hummm. I finally just check if the emitter isn't disposed of. I will updated my question...